# How to Paginate Firebase Firestore with Angular Material 2 Paginator?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, paginator

Hello I'm developing a Pokémon Web using Angular 5 and I need some help to fix my Material Angular 2 Paginator with Firestore.

I limited the Data query to show only 8

**My problem is that if I click to see the previous Data I dont know how to go back.**

I followed this in the Cloud Firestore documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

here is my code

```
page(event?: PageEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    this.todosCollection = this.afs.collection('entradas', ref => {
      ref.orderBy('fecha', 'desc').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(3).get().then( (documentSnapshots) => {
        // Get the last visible document
        console.log(documentSnapshots)
        console.log(documentSnapshots.docs)
        this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
        // console.log('last', this.lastVisible);
      });
      return ref.orderBy('fecha', 'desc').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(3);
    }); // reference

    this.todos = this.todosCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

when 'Todos' means 'AllPost' and the PageEvent returns for example `{pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10, length: 100}`

I want to know how to show for example in pageIndex 0 the first 3 items, in pageIndex 1 the next 3 items but if I go back and press the prev button the pageIndex will be 0 and I want to show the first 3 items again.

Thanks for read =D